# API for Real Time World Statistics

Tags: api, statistics, iphone

Does anyone know of an API (preferably free) that can provide real time world statistics such as [Crude Birth Rate, Crude Death Rate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birth_rate), world/country population, or emails sent today as on the website http://www.worldometers.info/?

I'm looking to connect the data to an iPhone app, and I can work with any sort of return type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not likely to be 'real-time' (data/censuses takes time to compile from all the countries around the world).

http://databank.worldbank.org/data/Databases.aspx

**and the databank API**

http://data.worldbank.org/developers

would be good starting points.